# Should I login to every Stack Exchange site independently?

Tags: support, accounts

I have a profile on Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow. I don't remember if Meta Stack Overflow asked me to create a separate login/profile and now I want to start with the other Stack Exchange sites from here: https://stackexchange.com/sites.

When I try to open a new site (let's say https://physics.stackexchange.com) it asks me to sign up. Is there any kind of single sign-on here? Should I use my login/password from Stack Overflow or should I create a new one?

I am not looking for complicated ways, I just want to know which is the simplest way to live with many Stack Exchange sites. What is the best way for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [How do I create an account?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/creating-accounts) (emphasis mine):

> In addition to creating an account for this site (and its associated [meta-discussion site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)), you will also have a Stack Exchange network profile, which is accessible from your user page on any site where you have an account. **This means that if you create an account on any other Stack Exchange site, it will be linked to your account here.** Once you’ve earned 200 reputation on at least one [Stack Exchange site](http://stackexchange.com/sites), you will receive a starting +100 reputation bonus to get you past basic new user restrictions. This will happen automatically on all current Stack Exchange sites where you have an account, and on any other Stack Exchange sites at the time you log in.

When you click the "Join this Community" button at the top of a Stack Exchange site you've not got an account for, do you not see the following?

> [image: You are about to create a new account...]

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for correcting my question. Only looking into your changes I realized that the names of these sites are different: https://*.stackoverflow.com/ and https://*.stackexchange.com/.
Unfortunately, I don't see such a form. When I get to the https://physics.stackexchange.com/ I see the button "Sign up to join this Community", although I already have StackOverflow and Meta StackOVerflow accounts. When I press this button it says "Create your Physics Stack Exchange account. " and asks to provide Display name, email and password. It doesn't ask to link.

Comment: Maybe this is because I still have no accounts at https://*.stackexchange.com/ and have only https://*.stackoverflow.com/ accounts?

Comment: @DamirTenishev - How do you authenticate your current profile?  If you use the same authentication your existing profile and the profile you will create at Physics SE will be linked.  However, the profile will still be new, so you will still be a new user on Physics SE

Comment: My browser stores the login and pass and when I open the link it substitutes them. With it I enter both meta.stackoverflow.com and stackoverflow.com. So, I use login and pass. What should I do to have linked profiles? Can I try with the same email and pass?

Comment: I just tried with the same name, login and pass at the physics.stackexchange.com and it worked, making the link. Thank you, this solved my problem.